# Prove that $\sup_x |\rho(x)-\rho_{\alpha}(x)| \leq |\rho'|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} |1_{x>0}-h_{\alpha}|_{L^1}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Let $\rho(x)$ be a function such that its derivative is bounded and its limit at $x \to -\infty$ exists. We can rewrite $\rho$ like so and define $\rho_{\alpha}$:

$$
\rho(x)=\rho(-\infty)+\int_{-\infty}^x\rho'(y) dy=\rho(-\infty)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\rho'(y)1_{x>0}(x-y) dy
$$
$$
\rho_{\alpha}(x)=\rho(-\infty)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\rho'(y)h_{\alpha}(x-y)dy
$$
where we define $h_{\alpha}$ as
$$
h_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\tanh(\alpha x))
$$

How do I show that the following holds?
$$
\sup_x |\rho(x)-\rho_{\alpha}(x)| \leq |\rho'|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} |1_{x>0}-h_{\alpha}|_{L^1}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

\begin{align*}|\rho(x)-\rho_{\alpha}(x)| &= \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\rho'(y)(1_{x>0}-h_\alpha)(x-y)  dy\right| \\ 
&\le \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\rho'(y)| \cdot |(1_{x>0}-h_\alpha)(x-y)\right|  dy \\
&\le \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\rho'|_{L^\infty}|(1_{x>0}-h_\alpha)(x-y)\right|  dy \\ &= |\rho'|_{L^\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}|(1_{x>0}-h_\alpha)(x-y)dy \\ &= |\rho'|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} |1_{x>0}-h_{\alpha}|_{L^1}
\end{align*}

The results follows by taking $\sup_x$ on both sides

Comment: Are you sure you can go from $|\rho'(y)$ to $|\rho'|_{L^{\infty}}$ in the integral? You're turning the function $\rho'$ into a constant...

Comment: Yes I am and yes I do.

Comment: Could you explain why briefly? Thank you for all your help so far

Comment: You should recap rules for the integral. If you have two functions $f \le g$ then it holds $$\int f(y) dy \le \int g(y) dy$$. Now take $$f(y) = \left|\rho'(y)| \cdot |(1_{x>0}-h_\alpha)(x-y)\right|$$ and $$g(y) = \left|\rho'|_{L^\infty}|(1_{x>0}-h_\alpha)(x-y)\right|$$

Comment: I'm dumb sorry, I understand now. It makes a lot of sense. Thank you!!